# Get Dynamic IP then Grep & Echo Hosts file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, echo

I have a dns & apachi server at our company, it's IP Address is dynamic
and i 'have tried to do the following:

```html
#!/bin/bash
# Get the dynamic IP (dirty, I know)
IP=`host -t a mychangingip.myip.com | perl -nle '/((?:\d+\.?){4})/ && print $1' | head -n1`
# Update the hosts file
if test -n "$IP"; then
    grep -v www.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
    echo "$IP www.thesite.com" >> /tmp/hosts
    cp /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
fi
```

so far this step works fine, but when i try to:

```html
#!/bin/bash
# Get the dynamic IP (dirty, I know)
IP=`host -t a mychangingip.myip.com | perl -nle '/((?:\d+\.?){4})/ && print $1' | head -n1`
# Update the hosts file
if test -n "$IP"; then
    grep -v www.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
    grep -v portal.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
    echo "$IP www.thesite.com" >> /tmp/hosts/
    echo "$IP portal.thesite.com" >> /tmp/hosts
    cp /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
fi
```

it doesn't work as expected and only updates one entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
grep -v www.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
grep -v portal.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
```

with:

```
grep -v www.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts2
grep -v portal.thesite.com /etc/hosts2 > /tmp/hosts
```

or, replace both lines with:

```
grep -v 'www.thesite.com\|portal.thesite.com' /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
```

#### Further simplication

Consider replacing these five lines:

```
grep -v www.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
grep -v portal.thesite.com /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts
echo "$IP www.thesite.com" >> /tmp/hosts/
echo "$IP portal.thesite.com" >> /tmp/hosts
cp /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
```

With this one line:

```
sed -i.bak "/www.thesite.com|portal.thesite.com/ s/[^[[:space:]]*/$IP/" /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For your reference:

```
grep -v 'www.thesite.com' /etc/hosts|grep -v 'portal.thesite.com' >/tmp/hosts
echo -e $IP'\t\t'www.thesite.com >> /tmp/hosts
echo -e $IP'\t\t'portal.thesite.com >> /tmp/hosts
cat /tmp/hosts > /etc/hosts
```